# What is the naming convention for database table public IDs

Tags: database-design

Let's say my table's name is

```
Entries
```

Then the id column of the table would be

```
EntryID
```

But what about a public ID? Here are some alternatives and my issues with them:

```
EntryID_public - postfix should be for content (_on), underscore should be avoided
EntryID_Public - postfix should not have uppercase
EntryIdPublic - could work, but acronyms with two letter should be capitalized according to some.
PublicID - too anonymous column name, no reference to its content
EntryIDPublic - three character acronym, looks bad and is hard to read.
```

So far I think the topmost alternative is the best one. What does the standards say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are no set rules, I have picked up and utilized some conventions over the years.  First off, I avoid using plural names for tables.  This is simply confusing.  In your example, I would name the table `entry`.

The id, would then be `entry_id`.

In my convention, _id designates that the entry_id is the primary key for that table, AND it is typically a numeric sequence number.

Other primary key types I use:

- table_code:  a char key.
- table_guid: a generated GUID.
- created_on: a creation timestamp
- updated_on: an update timestamp

This makes it very clear when you implement a foreign key relationship with another table, that the key (table_id) is coming from a specific table, and if you use an ER diagramming tool, they typically work well with this convention.

The only time I find that I need to rename a foreign key, is when there is a self referencing relationship, or in many to many resolutions where there are multiple foreign keys from the same table involved.  Typically these can easily be prefixed like this:

parent_person_id
child_person_id

In conclusion, I'm not entirely clear on what you mean by a public id?  If you mean, that you have a candidate key, then that should be named in a way that describes what the column actually is.  The prototypical example is SSN (social security number) for a person.

Answer (score 0):

> What does the standards say?

I dont think there is any such standards for naming it. You may name it as per your readability and easiness.

I prefer to name it like `EntryID_public` but it all depends on one's easiness and choice. Many may argue as they would find any other convention as more readable. But as far as naming convention standard is concerned there is **no** such standard.